# Cannot install TopShelf service using MSBuild and PSExec

Tags: .net, deployment, msbuild, psexec, topshelf

Having copied over the bin directory, I am attempting to install a Topshelf service from a TeamCity build server onto our dev server, using MSBuild & psexec:

```
<Exec Command="psexec \\$(ServerName) $(ServerBinDirLocal)\$(ProjectName).exe install -displayname $(ApplicationLongName) -description &quot;$(ServiceDescription)&quot; --networkservice --delayed" ContinueOnError="false" />
```

However, whatever combination of quotes I try, I always get:

```
The command "psexec \\srv06541wn d:\Bin\Service.DEV\Service.exe install ..." exited with code 9009.
```

This is a DNS error, apparently, but I can't see how this is the issue, as I am supplying a local and not UNC path. The build server account is an administrator on the destination server, so this should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's a couple possible solutions here but this isn't a Topshelf issue specifically. I'm guessing that 9009 is lie though.

1. The first possible is that you need the full path for psexec. `C:\...\psexec`. You can test this out by changing the command to be something really simple and making sure it works. `psexec` might not be on the path for TeamCity.
2. Verify that it works with the hostname without the FQDN. TeamCity might not have the same context as you do.

Comment: Thanks, Travis. We can rule out 2. as I am able to copy the files over successfully. I think the problem may be more 1. - asking around I am not sure that PSExec is even installed. Large security-zealous corporate environment and I still trying to get access to the boxes.

There are older windows services that are installed from the same TeamCity using SC.exe. I have tried reusing their scripts, but the service seems to hang on startup. Should that work?

Comment: Last line in the log file:

     2014-11-06 12:00:23,315 [1] DEBUG MassTransit.Transports.RabbitMq.RabbitMqTransportFactory - RabbitMQ connection created: thunderrabbitdev:5672//

Comment: Sadly, it looks like my only option for remoted deploying/installing services in this environment is to use SC.exe, so I have had to remove TopShelf...